# how to add " in a variable

Tags: velocity

I would like to add " chars into my string, is it possible?
I'm avoiding this problem using ' char however I would like to use " if possible, thanks

here is an example what I do (and of course it does not work):

```
#set($options="<option value="1">my value</option>")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try

```
#set($Q = '"')
#set($options="<option value=${Q}1${Q}>my value</option>")
```

Comment: Old (and useful) trick, but it actually does not use `"` character inside the String literal. +1 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
#set($options="<option value=\"1\">my value</option>")
```